# plotting different groups with ggplot without having geom_path connecting the groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot the following dataset:

```r
VF_benthic_vs_WC_prod <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "scenario"  , "gradient_no", "prod_ID"         , "prod_pct" |
     "Baseline", 1L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 29.86      |
     "Baseline", 2L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 14.69      |
     "Baseline", 3L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 12.45      |
     "Baseline", 4L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 13.67      |
     "Baseline", 5L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 10.71      |
     "N-30%"   , 1L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 39.12      |
     "N-30%"   , 2L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 21.91      |
     "N-30%"   , 3L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 17.54      |
     "N-30%"   , 4L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 17.12      |
     "N-30%"   , 5L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 12.5       |
     "P-30%"   , 1L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 30.15      |
     "P-30%"   , 2L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 15.01      |
     "P-30%"   , 3L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 12.59      |
     "P-30%"   , 4L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 13.71      |
     "P-30%"   , 5L           , "benthic_prod_pct", 10.72      |
     "Baseline", 1L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 70.14      |
     "Baseline", 2L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 85.31      |
     "Baseline", 3L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 87.55      |
     "Baseline", 4L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 86.33      |
     "Baseline", 5L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 89.29      |
     "N-30%"   , 1L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 60.88      |
     "N-30%"   , 2L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 78.09      |
     "N-30%"   , 3L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 82.46      |
     "N-30%"   , 4L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 82.88      |
     "N-30%"   , 5L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 87.5       |
     "P-30%"   , 1L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 69.85      |
     "P-30%"   , 2L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 84.99      |
     "P-30%"   , 3L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 87.41      |
     "P-30%"   , 4L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 86.29      |
     "P-30%"   , 5L           , "WC_prod_pct"     , 89.28      )
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

exactly as shown below as a figure from Excel:

[image: Production_vs_gradient_no - Excel]

However, when i try to plot with ggplot I get this:

[image: Production_vs_gradion_no - ggplot2]

Here´s my basic ggplot code:

```r
benthic_vs_WC_prod <- ggplot(data = VF_benthic_vs_WC_prod, aes(x = gradient_no, y = prod_pct, group = scenario)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = scenario, color = scenario, fill = scenario))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I suspect that I have to do something about the grouping but do not know what exactly.

All I need is to get the lines and the legend right - the layout, shapes and colors ect. I can fiddle around with myself.

Hope it all makes sense (new to reprex() and r in general)

Best,

Comment: I think you're right. Probably would be fixed if you set `group = interaction(scenario, prod_ID)`. (untested)

Comment: YES!, that did it with the lines. Now I just need to get the legend right. One legend for Benthic production and another for Water column production. Each with the scenarios included.

Comment: The easiest would be to use `geom_path(aes(linetype = prod_ID))`, but that doesn't give the two legends as you describe them.

Comment: Yes, not exactly the same legend as above but works just fine. Thx for the help